# Using Spring integration FTP client hangs after transfering the file in Docker

Tags: spring, docker, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm using the following code in order to connect to a FTP server:

```
public void sendData(BepReport bpReport) {

FtpSession ftpSession = defaultFtpSessionFactory.getSession();

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(bpReport.getReportName());
buffer.append(bpReport.getContent());

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    buffer.toString().getBytes());

log.info("Before writing the file named  {} to FTP Server", DESTINATION);
try {
  ftpSession.write(is, DESTINATION);
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("Error ",e);
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
log.info("After writing the file named  {} to FTP Server", DESTINATION);
ftpSession.close();

}
```

This runs as expected. However if the same code is put into the Docker container it hangs and doesn't return after creating the file on FTPServer and printing `log.info("Before writing the file named {} to FTP Server", DESTINATION)`.

What is the reason of not returning from `ftpSession.write`?

Comment: The methods write hangs also when using org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate.

Comment: I think there is a problem with connection. And I'm not sure in your `after creating the file on FTPServer` since there is in FTP interaction until you really call that `ftpSession.write()`. The `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` is redundant to mention here since it is fully based on the mentioned `FtpSession`. Look into your Docker container logs. Look into your FTP server logs. See if you can really ping your FTP server from that Docker container.

Comment: I've managed to make it write and not getting stucked în session or stream input on Ftp server by using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it write and not getting stucked in session or stream input on Ftp server by using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.
My advice is not to use Spring integration with ftp, try the basic org.apache.commons.net.ftp package when integrating Java client app with a Ftp sever.

Comment: Well, that's counterproductive: I would like to know what really is an issue with `FtpSession` where its `write()` use the mentioned `FTPClient.storeFile(path, inputStream)`. It is probably OK for you to stand against Spring Integration library, but that's really not how community works and there are many people who would like to use Spring Integration API and have it fixed if there is a bug. So, may we have more info to understand what is wrong with Spring Integration's `FtpSession`? More over you have claimed that it works without Docker...